# Qt creator with Breakpad

Tags: qt, qt-creator, google-breakpad

I want to deploy a crash handler with my Qt application that I've created with Qt creator.  After some poking around it would appear that Google's Breakpd will do exactly what I need it to do, however the tutorials on this are pretty light.  As a result I have a number of questions that I hope can get answered.

1. How do I create a Release with Debug info configuration in Qt creator?
2. I've followed the example [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/source/browse/trunk/src/processor/testdata/test_app.cc#) and am able to create a .dmp file on Windows.
3. How can I use Breakpad to transmit that dmp file to me automatically?
4. How can I read that file using Breakpad?

Currently I'm deploying my app on Windows, so I'm able to open the .dmp file in Visual Studios 2008 and see the debug info only if I build the app in debug mode (so I get the .pdb files).  However, I eventually want this to work on multiple platforms so I was wondering what tools Breakpad provides to create a stack trace outside of Visual Studios?

The tutorials on Breakpad seem pretty light, so if there is a good tutorial out there that would help as well I'd love to read it.

Thanks

OK, I think I have figured out the answer to 1.  If you add the following lines to your .pro file (just for release) you'll build release with debug info on

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE -= $$QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE += $$QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= $$QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += $$QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO
QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE -= $$QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE
QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE += $$QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO
```

I still need to figure out 3 and 4.  Any help would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at this project: https://github.com/AlekSi/breakpad-qt

Documentation for the project is pretty scarce, but at least it has subprojects `handler` and `sender` which could answer your questions #3 and #4.